# Unit test: patching os join overwrites os join in test file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pathlib

I'm writing a unit test for a function that creates a folder using `os.makedirs` and `os.path.join`. When I'm trying to mock the specific os.path.join used in the class BuilddataHelpers it also patches the `os.path.join` in the test file. How can I specifically patch the `os.path.join` in the file that is being tested while still using `os.path.join` in the test file?

datamanager/builddatahelpers.py

```
import os
PATH = 'not/test/data/either'

class BuilddataHelpers:
    def create_folder(self, folder_name):
        create_folder_path = os.path.join(PATH, folder_name)
        os.makedirs(create_folder_path, exist_ok = True)
        return path
```

datamanager/datamanager.py

```
class DataManager(BuilddataHelpers):
     ...
```

test_builddatahelpers.py

```
import os

class TestBuilddataHelpers(unittest.TestCase):
    global TEST_PATH 
    TEST_PATH = 'tests/data'

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestBuilddataHelpers, self).setUp()
        self.dm = DataManager()
    
    @patch('datamanager.builddatahelpers.os.path.join', return_value=TEST_PATH)
    def test_create_folder_structure_on_ftp(self, mock_os_join):
        folder_name = 'test_folder'
        self.dm.create_folder(folder_name)
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, folder_name)))
        print('SUBFOLDER PATH: ' , os.path.join('not', 'test', 'data'))
```

outputs `SUBFOLDER PATH: tests/data`. The folder is still created since `os.makedirs` is not patched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tested code, you do `import os`, which means that `os.path.join` will be used instead of a local reference. So if you do:

```py
    @patch('datamanager.builddatahelpers.os.path.join', return_value=TEST_PATH)
    def test_create_folder_structure_on_ftp(self, mock_os_join):
        ...
```

this is exactly the same as writing:

```py
    @patch('os.path.join', return_value=TEST_PATH)
    def test_create_folder_structure_on_ftp(self, mock_os_join):
        ...
```

That first version only would make sense if you had used `from x import y` in the tested code. In your case, `os.path.join` will be patched for all modules using it.
If you want to use the original `os.path.join`, you have to cache it somewhere.
One possibility is to just use:

```py
from os.path import join

...
    @patch('os.path.join', return_value=TEST_PATH)
    def test_create_folder_structure_on_ftp(self, mock_os_join):
        folder_name = 'test_folder'
        self.dm.create_folder(folder_name)
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(join(TEST_PATH, folder_name)))
        print('SUBFOLDER PATH: ' , join('not', 'test', 'data'))
```

The local reference to `os.path.join` saved in `join` will not be patched. You could also cache it as a class variable:

```py
import os

class TestBuilddataHelpers(unittest.TestCase):
    TEST_PATH = 'tests/data'
    join = os.path.join
...

    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(self.join(TEST_PATH, folder_name)))
```

which shall have the same effect.

Comment: Well put! I need to re-read up on some stuff regarding patching apparently. Thanks for taking you time.